# Issues Saving Long String Option

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options

I created a theme option in The Customizer using `$wp_customize`. Everything works well but it has a problem with saving the long text. If my input value has more than 179 characters, it won't save!

When I look at the browser console `admin-ajax.php` status is aborted.

How can I resolve this problem?

I don't think is an issue with my server configuration. All options for `php.ini` is checked and there's no problem in post or memory limit or other like this:

```
php.ini
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 1G
post_max_size = 128M
max_input_time = 120
```

Part of the php code :

```
<?php
function prefix_register_customizer($wp_customize){    
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'homeQueTab', # Section ID to use in Option Table
    array( # Arguments array
         'title' => __( 'tabs', 'prefix' ), # Translatable text, change the text domain to your own
         'description' => __( 'manage tabs ', 'prefix' ),
         'panel'       => 'panelHome'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_setting('prefixOptions[homeQeTabDesc]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
        'default'       => '', # Default custom text
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('prefixOptions[homeQeTabDesc]', array(
            'label' => 'tab content', # Label of text form
            'section' => 'homeQueTab', # Layout Section
            'type' => 'text', # Type of control: text input , url , number , password , email
    ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'prefix_register_customizer');
```

Comment: Please include the PHP code you're using to register the setting, control, and section.

Comment: tnaks, part of code added @WestonRuter

Comment: I juste try the code and I put in a string of 920 caracters without problems. Have you tried to desactivate all plugins to see if the problem is always here.